# The property $xxx is not a valid price specification in Magento2

Tags: magento2, rich-snippets

"Also referring here for the issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5022 - Microdata related issue for Magento 2 site"

> Price property is currently not well recognized in Google Structured
>   Data testing tool.

What could be the temp yet effective solution to this issue?

thanks!

Comment: Upgrage ur Magento CE Version to latest 2.1.2.

Comment: according to here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7173 this issue remains in M2.1.2